# Which errors should be thrown in Go?

Tags: go, error-handling

Because I come from python I am aware of throwing exceptions or general error handling.

Now I wrote the following code in go:

```golang
func AddHeaders(headers map[string]string, request *http.Request) (*http.Request, error) {
    for key, value := range headers {
        request.Header.Set(key, value)
    }
    return request, nil
}
```

So this should be work, but maybe I should throw an error if header set failed, like:

```
request.Header.Set(key, value)
header := request.Header.Get(key)
if header != value {
    return nil, errors.New("failed to add header")
}
```

Because I also try to unit test most of my code I recognize that it is nearly impossible to trigger this error and so I asked myself if it is good or bad practice to throw this error?

Comment: If `request.Header.Set` can fail, it should return an error on its own. You should not do that from outside.

Comment: You should _return_ errors whenever it makes sense, like if you're writing to a file or doing something that can potentially fail. Nothing in `AddHeaders` returns an error, so I don't see a point in `AddHeaders` returning an error.

Comment: You should "throw" an error whenever an error is defined and possible (in Go, you return errors, rather than throwing them). The documentation (https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Header.Set) does not say that the function can fail (it doesn't return an error, after all), so if it does, then there's a bug in the implementation of the standard library that you're using. Unless you have a legitimate reason to believe such a bug exists, you shouldn't be checking for them. And if you do have such a legitimate reason, you should file a bug report.

Comment: I would say it is a good idea to handle errors if something returns an error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Which errors should be thrown in Go?

None. Go doesn't even have the ability to "throw" errors.

In Go, errors are normal values, and are thus returned as normal values.

In your code example, the only reason you'd need/want to return an error, is if there is some way that adding headers might result in an error.  Perhaps you'd want to return an error in case of a duplicate header, for instance:

```golang
func AddHeaders(headers map[string]string, request *http.Request) (*http.Request, error) {
    for key, value := range headers {
        if request.Header.Get(key) != "" {
            return nil, fmt.Errorf("Header key %s already set", key)
        }
        request.Header.Set(key, value)
    }
    return request, nil
}
```

But honestly, that probably doesn't make sense. So you can probably just eliminate the error value from the return list entirely:

```golang
func AddHeaders(headers map[string]string, request *http.Request) *http.Request {
    for key, value := range headers {
        request.Header.Set(key, value)
    }
    return request
}
```

And in this specific example, you don't need to return the request, either. You can just modify it in place:

```golang
func AddHeaders(headers map[string]string, request *http.Request) {
    for key, value := range headers {
        request.Header.Set(key, value)
    }
}
```